# Keep Switch value when restarting the activity in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using a `Switch` in my app and by default, the value of the `Switch` if false, when I set this `Switch` to true and then, I leave this activity and enter again, the value restart to default value.

How can I keep the value when restarting the activity?

This is my `Switch` control:

```html
<Switch HorizontalOptions="Center"
        x:Name="mySwitch"
        IsToggled="{Binding ToggledState ,Mode=TwoWay}"
        Toggled="OnToggled"/>
```

## My code:

```
  public partial class MainPage: ContentPage {
    private bool IsSwitchToggled = true;
    public ViewModel viewmodel;

    public MainPage() {
      viewmodel = new ViewModel();

      ...
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing() {
      ...
    }

    void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) {
      if (IsSwitchToggled) {
        IsSwitchToggled = false;

      } else {

        viewmodel.DoSomething(e.Value);

      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you reopening a menu within the same instance of the application or are you completely restarting the application?

Comment: I'm reopening the menu in the same intance

Comment: Store your value to config file or SQLite database

Comment: Can you give me a little sample to know how to store the value ina config file? I don't find how to do this

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do it.
In your case. Declare the boolean in your App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
   public static bool IsSwitchToggled = true;
}
```

and then access it in your pages with

```
App.IsSwitchToggled
```

Assign the value to the switch in your viewModel and on the PageLoad with

```
youSwitchName.IsToggled = App.IsSwitchToggled;
```

When updating the switch value, Also update the App.IsSwitchToggled

```
App.IsSwitchToggled = true; // false
```

There are other easy way to do it such as storing it in Preferences using Essential plugin.

```
Preference.Set(nameof(stringName),false); 
Preference.Get(nameof(stringName),false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the state of the switch within the given application instance: declare a global variable.

Otherwise look into ways to store on the given device.

Comment: I edited my post with my code using a global variable but can't make it work.

Comment: You've put it in a content page, which you would only be able to access if you had a reference to it. You should put the switch bool in the Application instance, i.e. inside App.xaml.cs (assuming you've used the autogenerated template), that has "public partial class App : Application" at the top. As in ARH's answer.